# unable to install matplotlib

Tags: python

I get the following error trying to install matplotlib in python3.5 in ubuntu16.04 LTS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to install it with `pip`? While it is packaged.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```